# Node.js Server-Client communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, client, discord.js

I have a discord bot and i want to make a website for the bot. For example I want to get the discord server members and print out to the website in a header or something else. Or if a button on the page was clicked, then the bot send a message to a channel. Can you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install a node package called Express using a command: npm install --save express . you have to do:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = app.listen(3000);
    app.use(express.static('public'));//name of the website folder that has the html and js files.
```

that will host a server on localhost:3000. Then you will need to run the code on the node js server when a button is clicked like you said. For that you'll need to use sockets.
You need another node package called socket.io. so just run npm install --save socket.io

and then write down

```
    var socket = require('socket.io')
    var io = socket(server);

    io.sockets.on("connection", function(Socket){
      console.log("new connection " + Socket.id);
      Socket.on("sendMessage", function(data){
        //send a discord message.
      });
    });
```

Alright now on to the client.

In the HTML file you need to reference the socket library.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
```

In the js file you need to write this.

```
    var socket;
    socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");

    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
      var data = {};
      socket.emit("sendMessage", data);
    });
```

That will send a request to the server and when the server receives it it will run the code you typed in:

```
  Socket.on("sendMessage")
```

the website url is on localhost:3000. and its only availabe on you PC, its different to make it public.

I hope this helped ya!